# How to get reseting entity with Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want get old entity from database for save history changed.

Now i have a code:

```
// Old version 1!
$app = $appManager->findByAppleId(547409501);
$app->setVersion('1.1');
$oldApp = $appManager->findByAppleId(547409501);
print $app->getVersion() . '<br />' . $oldApp->getVersion();
```

But app and old app have version 1.1. In DB app have version 1

P.S.

->findByAppleId - get repository and use function "find" (Apple ID is primary key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solution:

1. Get unitOfWork from entity manager in doctrine core
2. Get object hash by primary key
3. Remove this entity hashed

Code:

```
/**
 * @{inerhitDoc}
 */
public function clearAppHashInUnitOfWork($appleId)
{
 // Get unit of work (Doctrine::EntityManager)
 $uow = $this->container
     ->get('doctrine')
     ->getEntityManager()
     ->getUnitOfWork();

 // Get app hash by ID
 $appHash = $uow
     ->tryGetByIdHash(
       $appleId,
       $this->container->getParameter('app.app_class')
     );

 // Hash already exists
 if ($appHash) {
   $uow
       ->removeFromIdentityMap($appHash);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If must get changed fields, can use:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate